# Typescript Download PDF file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, typescript

I am trying to download this PDF file using this `AJAX Post` and returning the templateFile Model. I am getting the error cannot convert type TemplateFileDto to IhttpActionResult. Should I Return something different? Any help would be great.

```
printItems(versionKeys: string[]): JQueryPromise<any> {
        console.log('printItems');
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: JSON.stringify(versionKeys),
            url: this.apiUrls.PrintTemplates,
            success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                var file = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/pdf' });
                var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
                window.open(fileURL);


                console.log('success');

            }
        });

        return;
    }
```

Controller

```
[HttpGet, HttpPost]
[ApplicationApiAuthorize("Administrator, ContentManager")]
public IHttpActionResult PrintTemplates([FromBody] List<string> versionKeys)
{

    var templates = versionKeys
            .Select(v => TemplatesDataService.GetTemplate(v))
            .ToList();

    var templateIds = templates.Select(b => b.Id).ToList();

    var templateFile = TemplatesDataService.PrintTemplate(templateIds);

    return templateFile;
}
```

Model

```
 public class TemplateFileDto
    {
        public long? Id { get; set; }
        public byte[] Content { get; set; }
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public string ContentType { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: `return Ok(templateFile);`

Comment: What would I change in the ts code?

Comment: Your typescript code doesn't need to change, at least not to resolve the C# error you're seeing.

Comment: Do I not need to set the Blob to the Content byte[]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return type for your `PrintTemplates` method is `IHttpActionResult`; however, the type of your `templateFile` variable is `TemplateFileDto`.

Since there's no relationship between `TemplateFileDto` and `IHttpActionResult` (e.g., `TemplateFileDto` doesn't implement the `IHttpActionResult` interface), the compiler cannot implicitly convert this variable to the appropriate type - hence the error.

You can find more detailed information on this error [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0266).

The easiest way to resolve this is by calling the [`Ok` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/dn314591(v=vs.118)), with `templateFile` as a parameter. This will take care of making sure the content you return is formatted correctly and the HTTP response code is set to 200.

It should be as simple as changing your `PrintTemplates` method from this:

```
return templateFile;
```

To this:

```
return Ok(templateFile);
```

Comment: I get `Failed to load PDF document.`  something like this web browser blob:http://localhost:52313/17ccaaf8-3bf5-44dc-a6db-e2dcb262cb39

Comment: @Jefferson That link doesn't work for me. Might try asking that as a separate SO question, as it doesn't necessarily seem related to the problem discussed here.